# TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'

Tags: python, pytest

This error occurred during automated testing of a python project on the CI server using `pytest`. I'm using `pytest==4.0.2`. This error only just started to occur, previous pipelines seem to work fine.

The full error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/tmpdir.py", line 35, in TempPathFactory
    lambda p: Path(os.path.abspath(six.text_type(p)))
TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'
```

Comment: Add your code please or prepare minimum example.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`pytest` seems to have the package `attrs` as a dependency. `attrs==19.2.0` was released around `2019-10-01 17:00 UTC`. This seems to cause the problem above.

Switching back to `attrs==19.1.0` fixes the problem. Just do the following:

```
pip install attrs==19.1.0
```

**NOTE**: I expect that the issue will be resolved either by `attrs` or `pytest` soon by releasing a new version. So this fix should only be temporary.

From the comments: This error does not occur on the newer versions of pytest i.e. `pytest==5.2.0`

Comment: I confirm, best action is to update `pytest` to a more recent version.

Comment: I think there is a missing `=` sign in the version pinning. It should be `pip install --upgrade attrs==19.1.0`

Comment: I confirm this was an unexpected dependency that I had to install manually.

Answer (score 10):

pytest fixed using deprecated keyword `convert` at 3.6.3 (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-3-6-3-2018-07-04).
At 4.0.1, pytest merged code using `convert` (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4427).
This code was fixed on 5.2.0 (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4795).

Answer (score 8):

pytest version 5.3.1 with attrs Version 19.3.0 works fine for me.
[To check the pytest Version and attrs Version issue the following command:]

```
pip show pytest attrs
```

**I solved the same problem by upgrading pytest module via pip command:**

```
pip install -U pytest
```

Answer (score 5):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytest
```

(anaconda prompt or cmd)

this should solve your problem, as an updated version of pytest automatically takes care of attr issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with `aws-encryption-cli` v2.
I have updated my `aws-cdk.core` lib and it work again with migrate to `aws-encryption-cli` V2.

```
pip install -U aws-cdk.core
```

V2 doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/crypto-cli-examples.html#cli-example-encrypt-file

github bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3293

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that with `attrs==19.2.0` the `convert` attribute was removed ([source](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id96)).

`attr.ib(convert=int)` should be deprecated and replaced by `attr.ib(converter=int)`

You either need to update whatever is using attrs or you need to downgrade: `pip install 'attrs<19.2.0'`

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the command

```
conda update conda
```

and restart your system.