# How to fix pytest 5.2 execution returning TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pytest

My Ubuntu 18.04 setup.

```
$python --version
Python 3.7.4
$pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

$ pip show pytest attrs
Name: pytest
Version: 5.2.1
Summary: pytest: simple powerful testing with Python
Home-page: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/
Author: Holger Krekel, Bruno Oliveira, Ronny Pfannschmidt, Floris Bruynooghe, Brianna Laugher, Florian Bruhin and others
Author-email: None
License: MIT license
Location: /home/stoyan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: atomicwrites, attrs, pluggy, more-itertools, wcwidth, py, importlib-metadata, packaging
---
Name: attrs
Version: 19.3.0
Summary: Classes Without Boilerplate
Home-page: https://www.attrs.org/
Author: Hynek Schlawack
Author-email: hs@ox.cx
License: MIT
Location: /home/stoyan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

I explicitly state the versions of both pytest and attrs above, because my problem is similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189683/typeerror-attrib-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-convert), where the accepted answer was to update the versions, but that didn't work for me since my versions are more recent.

When I execute `pytest --help` I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stoyan/anaconda3/bin/pytest", line 6, in <module>
    from pytest import main
  File "/home/stoyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _pytest.fixtures import fixture, yield_fixture
  File "/home/stoyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 839, in <module>
    class FixtureFunctionMarker(object):
  File "/home/stoyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 841, in FixtureFunctionMarker
    params = attr.ib(convert=attr.converters.optional(tuple))
TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'
```

Comment: To elaborate why I think it's a dupe: the packages you listed are not used in the test runs (instead, you use another Python installation under `/home/stoyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/`). Check what's installed there, bump the versions and test again. Or use the system Python installation where you have the updated packages.